# Mysql to PDO fetch from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I'm trying to learn how to go from mysql statements to writing PDO statements.

I have my database setup and its connecting, but now I'm trying to figure out how to pull data from my tables.

Here is a simple example.
This is what I used to do...

```
<?php
$images = mysql_query("SELECT title FROM knollsnews ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4");
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
{

    ?>

<li><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/notices/notice.php?id=<?=$image["id"] ?>"><?=$image["title"] ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to convert this to the PDO method.

I've tried the following but can't seem to get this to work.

```
<?php
$images = mysql_query("SELECT `title` FROM knollsnews ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 4");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    while($result = $image->fetch()){

    ?>
```

I've read the manuals and Google for ways to convert this, but for the life of me can't seem to understand it.

With my old way I currently get an error on this line:

```
while ($image=mysql_fetch_array($images))
```

What is the PDO equivalent to this? That might help me out.

I'm not looking for a write this for me answer, but feel if I could see a real world example of my code converted it would help me out. If someone could point me in the right direction here I would appreciate it.

**Update** 
After doing some reading I realized in the system im using on my site I need to create another method of connecting to my database.
Here is my local setup:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=knolls', 'root', 'pdslo');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

?>
```

Here is my new formatted code:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/inc/database.php");
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `title` FROM `knollsnews` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 4";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();

foreach($query->fetchAll() as $img){
    ?>
<li><a href="notices/notice.php?id=<?php echo $img->id; ?>">
            <?php echo $img-> title; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Now the only error I'm getting is:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 13

Which is this: `<?php echo $img-> title; ?>`

I don't get why it's saying title is a non-object?

Comment: which particular tutorial you have read and got your code from?

Comment: You're using `mysql_query` in the PDO example too, that is definitely not supposed to be there.

Comment: @YourCommonSense [this](http://hirengprajapati.blogspot.com/2012/09/php-pdo-fetch-methods.html) [and this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks I'll go read about this.

Comment: **why don't you follow the first one then?** I can't see the code from there in your question.

Comment: I guess I got more reading / learning on my own to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I did a some more research and updated my question, any ideas as to why I'm getting that error?

Comment: Yes, I am reading it already. this one seems quite a simple one - by default an array returned, not the object. try to change $img-> title to $img['title'];

Comment: @YourCommonSense That was the issue. Thank you for the help, much appreciated. You want to post that as an answer so I can close this?
Also I got banned from asking questions on here. Anyway you can help lift that band. I won't ask anymore questions without fully researching the issue first. =)

Comment: That's good idea. I won't answer as the issue is quite trifle one. Besides, I reverted my downvote, so, may be it will revert your ability to post as well.